# How to setup testkitchen with ansible-provisioning from localhost for different vagrant-vms?

Tags: ansible, testing, vagrant

As pointed out [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-to-test-provisioning-and-configuration-in-ansible-setup), testkitchen is in principable usable with ansible if the right plugins are installed.

Now I've done all the installing and am at the point, where I wonder, what I missunderstood:

As a driver I use vagrant and I thought it might be a good idea to use the vagrant-host as the machine which does the ansible-provisoning since the ssh-access is obviously cared for by vagrant and python is installed on my boxes per default. Now, when I look at my logs, I see:

> Setting up ansible (2.4.1.0-1ppa~xenial) ...

How can I prevent the installing of ansible? How can I tell testkitchen to use localhost as the machine which provisions the vagrant vms?

To be more clear, I am trying to find a configuration for testkitchen ([as seen e.g. here under "Example .kitchen.yml file"](https://github.com/neillturner/kitchen-ansible)) that can accomplish this.

So far I got this configuration in my .kitchen.yml:

```
[...]
provisioner:
    name: ansible_playbook
    hosts: localhost
    require_chef_for_busser: false
    require_ruby_for_busser: false
    playbook: server.yml
[...]
```

This still installs ansible on the vagrant boxes, which I don't want.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html) it is possible to install ansible and run a ansible playbook by using the following snippet:

> ```
> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>
>   #
>   # Run Ansible from the Vagrant Host
>   #
>   config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
>     ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
>   end
>
> end
> ```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my description was not good, since I am not very familiar with the necessary termology. What I try to achiv is some kind of configuration for testkitchen ([like here](https://github.com/neillturner/kitchen-ansible)), so it is possible to run the ansible-process from localhost and provision several vagrant boxes, without installing ansible on them.